# Can you drop the bombs of an F-16 during 9G-forces?

Tags: fighter, aircraft-physics, g-forces

An F-16 simulator instructor told me that it is not possible to drop the bombs of an F-16 during 9 G-forces. I was surprised by this fact and looked it up, but I couldn't find anything about this. So I was wondering if this is true and why is that the case? Is this a safety issue?

Comment: It might be *mechanical*.  In other words, 9G might tear something before it had a chance to completely release.  Also, 9G might become alot more momentarily from weight loss, which could overstress the plane and be dangerous to the pilot.  Aircraft have been known to "toss" bombs while turning, so limits will vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a blanket truthfullness.

"Bombs" range all the way from a 25LB BDU-33 practice munition, to a 2,500LB [GBU-15](https://www.af.mil/About-Us/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/104578/gbu-15-guided-bomb-unit/). Different limits may apply.

*Generally speaking*, with large bombs and/or fuel tanks loaded, the jet is limited to 5.5-6.5G. The FLCC (Flight Control Computer and SMS (Stores Management System) work in conjunction to control this. This can be overridden by the pilot.

Also, "9G" is variable. A flat turn is different than a dive and pull up. Or, a "9G" turn, but you're already mostly inverted. Is the munition going to release cleanly and on target?

But if you're in a situation where you need to be pulling a 9G turn, you would have ejected the munitions anyway. The thing would wallow like a whale otherwise.

Fun off-topic factoid: The F-16A/B flight and design parameters are closer to the P-51 than to the F-35.

Answer (score 3):

Not likely as the pylons capable of carrying bombs, i.e. stations 3, 4, 6 and 7 are load limited to 7.5 Gs.  Push beyond that and you risk structural damage with an air-to-ground loadout.  It’s also possible that the fire control computer does not offer computations for weapons release beyond those load factors as well. And it would be pretty hard to get off an accurate shot using a freefall dumb bomb, straining hard like that.

Comment: When I worked in munition development, the highest load at release that we tested was 4g - all on the F-16. That was about 40+ inert weapon releases and about 2 dozen live weapons. The SEEK EAGLE program office (who certifies a/c+weapon loadout and safe separation) used the test data and their aero models to set the ultimate limits that were put in the software.  And to your last comment, using continuously computed release point (CCRP) mode, the the FCC will release it quite accurately with no issue if you're within limits.